# Moving horizontal line in excel chart

Tags: excel-2016

I have an updating volume profile chart in excel for SPX. What I'm trying to do is to insert a current price line that will move as the price moves up and down. I've found something close, but the problem is that the y-axis with prices are #2 $5 apart, so they are 4255, 4260, 4265..., while the price #1 of SPX moves every cent i.e. 4255.55, 4255.56... The line should appear at #3, but everything I tried, the line #4 always appears all the way at the bottom of the chart at 4180.

I saw someone on youtube had what I'm looking for #5, so I know it can be done.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fleiW.png)

I've looked all over for a solution, but can't find it.